# Variable access performance

Tags: android, performance, static

I'm developing an app that has a DataManager class, which holds an `ArrayList<Object[]>`. As this ArrayList needs to be used within other classes, I am wondering what would be the most efficient and fastest way of accessing this list, considering this application will be running on the Android platform.

A) create a `public static ArrayList<Object[]> data` in the DataManager class and reference it within other classes through `DataManager.data`

B) create a `public ArrayList<Object[]> getData` method within the DataManager class and have methods within other classes create local variable `ArrayList<Object[]> data = mDataManager.getData()` for temporary use.

C) ..?

It seems to me B has more overhead due to object creation. Also I read static is faster than non-static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option B does not increase memory use, since you will only have one `ArrayList` object (all the objects that use it just hold a simple reference, not a copy). The objects that use the `ArrayList` could also store this reference as an instance variable, instead of requesting it from the manager class each time it is needed.

I read somewhere that access to instance variables is slightly faster than accessing class (`static`) variables, but I don't have the link to the source.

The difference in performance is not likely to be meaningful. However, Option B gives you better encapsulation.

Comment: That being said, option B would be the same as option A, both referencing the same object. What about performance accessing a static member vs creating a local member through a public method?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question the first time.
Local variables are typically faster than `static`. Option B imposes the slight overhead of a method call, but nothing of significance. Focus on the clarity of the design and let the compiler take care of optimizing the code.

Comment: How about C) creating the data variable in DataManager non-static and access it directly from the other classes, neglecting encapsulation? Or will the performance gain be neglectable so it would be better to use proper OOP and use option B?

Comment: I would make it a non-static member variable in `DataManager` and let other classes access it via a `getData` method. It's the cleanest from an OO perspective. You could make the getter `final` and the compiler will likely inline in.